# Uploading bytearray via URLRequest

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to upload a bytearray, but am struggling to make the content-type go as image/png (it always goes as application/octet-stream no matter what I do.).

I've checked the request with Charles Proxy, and can confirm that it indeed always goes as application/octet-stream.

My code is:

```
protected function onObjectLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var fileName:String = fileReference.name;
    var uploadPath:String = serviceURL;
    var parameters:Object = new Object();
    parameters.key = serviceKey;

    fileReference.data.readBytes(byteArray,0,fileReference.data.length);

    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    urlRequest.url = uploadPath;
    urlRequest.contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + UploadPostHelper.getBoundary();
    urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
    urlRequest.data = UploadPostHelper.getPostData(fileName, byteArray, "fileupload",  parameters);
    urlRequest.requestHeaders.push( new URLRequestHeader( 'Content-type', 'image/png' ) );

    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
    /*urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
    urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);*/
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processResults);
    urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
}
```

As you can see, I;m passing the content type as "multipart/form-data". I've tried passing it as image/png, which made the request itself go as image/png as expected, however, the image itself still goes as application/octet-stream.

Here's what my request looks like right now:

> --rojpkvwesrtjvrgjbwtadelavgcmxjot Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name="key"
>
> WZL0NXBE6dcb9af80668bb96b86fa72f5595422c
>   --rojpkvwesrtjvrgjbwtadelavgcmxjot Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name="Filename"
>
> Canada.png
>   --rojpkvwesrtjvrgjbwtadelavgcmxjot Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name="fileupload"; filename="Canada.png" Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream
>
> ‰PNG -- **Loads of image information here as a bytearray**

As you can see Canada.png is being passed in as application/octet-stream. I've fiddled with the request, and have manually made it work, as to what my server expected to receive, which is exactly the same as above, but where it says:

> Canada.png
>   --rojpkvwesrtjvrgjbwtadelavgcmxjot Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name="fileupload"; filename="Canada.png" Content-Type:
>   **application/octet-stream**

It should say:

> Canada.png
>   --rojpkvwesrtjvrgjbwtadelavgcmxjot Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name="fileupload"; filename="Canada.png" Content-Type:
>   **image/png**

My question is how to change this, so the bytearray itself gets passed in as image/png instead of octet-stream

This image is being upload from the client side, and being passed as a FileReference, which I then invoke load(), and then get it's "data" attribute, which is where the bytearray is.

Any help here would be much appreciated, as I've been struggling with this for a few hours, but can't seem to be able to change the mime type of the bytearray.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content-type in your request is set inside UploadPostHelper class. As far as I can tell it is hard-coded as application/octet-stream. You can just change it to image/png if you only going to upload png images. Or you can use another url request wrapper for uploading files that allows you to specify content-type of a file. For example [MultipartURLLoader](http://code.google.com/p/in-spirit/source/browse/trunk/projects/MultipartURLLoader/).

Comment: You sir.. are a bloody genius! I cannot believe I didn't think of that. I've started using this wrapper and completely forgot about it until you mentioned! Thank you so much! I'll also have a look at  MultipartURLLoader